# Texstudio returns error

Tags: errors, undefined

I try to run this beamer in Texstudio. But I encounter,
"Undefined control sequence. \end{frame}." The beamer compiles in overleaf but not in Texstudio.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{rtsched}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{pstricks}
\usepackage{keyval}
\title{An example of using the \texttt{rtsched} package with Beamer}
\author{Giuseppe Lipari}
\institute[Scuola Superiore Sant'Anna]{Scuola Superiore Sant'Anna -- Pisa}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{An example with fixed priority}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{RTGrid}[width=10cm]{2}{20}
        %% the first job of task 1 arrives at time 0,
        %% with a relative deadline of 4
        \TaskArrDead{1}{0}{4}
        %% the second job arrives at time 4
        \TaskArrDead{1}{4}{4}
        %% etc
        \TaskArrDead{1}{8}{4}
        \TaskArrDead{1}{12}{4}
        \TaskArrDead{1}{16}{4}
        %% the task executes in intervals [0,1], [4,5], etc.
        \TaskExecution{1}{0}{1}
        \TaskExecution{1}{4}{5}
        \TaskExecution{1}{8}{9}
        \TaskExecution{1}{12}{13}
        \TaskExecution{1}{16}{17}
        %% the second task
        \TaskArrDead{2}{0}{4}
        \TaskArrDead{2}{6}{4}
        \TaskArrDead{2}{12}{4}
        \TaskExecution{2}{1}{4}
        \TaskExecution{2}{6}{8}
        \TaskExecution{2}{9}{10}
        \TaskExecution{2}{13}{16}
      \end{RTGrid}

  \end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks for your solutions

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. TeXstudio is a front-end to a back-end TeX distribution. Which TeX distribution is installed on your computer, and when did you last update this TeX distribution? Separately, what exactly did this "undefined control sequence" error message refer to? Maybe that the file `rtsched.sty` couldn't be found on your system? Please be specific.

Comment: Please cite the exact error, preferably the entire log file as you compile this exact example on your system.

Comment: @Mico I have MiKTeX-pdfTeX 2.9.7338 . I have installed the latest update. I have no error on line /usepackage{rtsched}, but line /begin{RTGrid} shows unrecognized environment. So is it the missing package if so how can I fix it please?

Comment: probably unrelated to the error but `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` are you sure you are using latin1 not utf-8 input (I didn't think that was even possible at overleaf, I think the editor only supprts utf-8 (as does this site))

Comment: After running with `xelatex` it compiles. Thanks